# Duplicated objects are moving back to their original position. Is this a bug?

Tags: modeling, animation

I am making a classroom scene where I am getting some weird bug.

As you can see in the file, I am trying to duplicate the chair to put it to the students who don't have it.

The thing is I am able to do it but while editing I noticed that the duplicated chairs are getting back to its original position (where they were at time of duplicating).

Also, even if I save the file after putting the chairs back to every student while loading, they simply disappear.

Let me know please what is happening in here

Link to file : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uph2th0q53iys0z/undo%20error.blend?dl=0

EDIT : There actually was a keyframe but though i didnt have dope sheet visible so didnt know about that . Thanks alot @Cegaton for helping out .

Comment: Are there any keyframes assigned to the original object?

Comment: Omg didnt realize that ,there actually was a keyframe .  thnx so much sir , iam new to blender and was really having a tough time with this .